# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline 'Configure your pipeline' getting skipped

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOPs, when trying to create build pipeline, the 'Configure your pipeline' option is getting skipped and it takes straight to 'Review' tab. We want to configure using 'yaml' for Dev branch. The Repo has a 'Master' and a 'Dev' branch. Below is the snip of the 'Configure' tab (from other tenant) which is getting skipped. I have checked that this is not related to 'Edit build pipeline' security setting. I was not able to find any other relevant security setting which may be causing this. What can be the issue?

Anhy help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. This is because my repository had a azure-pipelines.yml file at the root level. Deleting it or renaming it fixed the issue